# Encrypt and decrypt Url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net mvc 5. I have two pages. The first page with a field is to enter the new PIN, the second page is to re-enter the new PIN

I have the url when a submit form in first page to pass the cardID and new PIN, such as:

```
.../ChangePIN/ConfirmPIN?cardID=123456789&newPIN=123456
```

and I want to encrypt `"cardID = 123456789"` and `"newPIN = 123456"`, so how can I do?

```
namespace ATM.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ChangePINController : Controller
    {
        ATMDb ATMContext = new ATMDb();
        string cardID = ATM.Core.Utilities.MyUtilities.getInstance().Card.CardId;
        //
        // GET: /Card/ChangePIN
        public ActionResult ChangePIN(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var card = ATMContext.Card.Find(id);
            if (card == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.cardID = id;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ConfirmPIN(string cardID, string newPIN)        
        {
            ViewBag.cardID = cardID;
            ViewBag.newPIN = newPIN;
            return View();
            }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ConfirmPIN(string cardID, string newPIN, string newPINConfirm)
        {
            if (newPIN != newPINConfirm)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "";
                ViewBag.cardID = cardID;
                ViewBag.newPIN = newPIN;
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
               var card = ATMContext.Card.Find(cardID);     
                ATMContext.Entry(card).State = EntityState.Modified;                 
                card.PIN = newPINConfirm;
                ATMContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Success()
        {
            return View();
        }        
    }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks you everyone.

Comment: Why dont you use `Post` for sensitive information?

Answer (score 2):

In encrypted url, the requester must know the encryption if it is open for all get requests.
If you are using internal links in your views you can create static class(Utility) for same. ex

```
  public static Encryption{
  public static string encrypt(string ToEncrypt)
        {
              return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ToEncrypt));
        }
        public static string decrypt(string cypherString)
        {
              return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(cypherString));
        }
}
```

In your view use :

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "Action_name", "Controller_name", new { id=Encryption.encrypt(article.ArticleID) }, null)
```

And you must decrypt before using Id ex.

```
 public ActionResult ChangePIN(string id)
        {
        string _id=Encryption.decrypt(id);
        ...
        }
```

Hope it will help.